# In dovecot, what syntax to use if I have a space in mysql password?

Tags: linux, mysql, dovecot

I'm trying to configure Dovecot to access mysql, but it's not working because there is a space in the mysql password.

```
driver = mysql
connect = "host=localhost dbname=postfix user=postfix password=blah bluh blih"
```

When I'm trying to access a mailbox from Thunderbird / Evoution, I'm getting this error :

```
Jan 05 14:41:11 mx1 dovecot[28895]: auth: Fatal: mysql: Missing value in connect string: bluh
```

I can't find the proper syntax to make it work. Has someone an idea ?

Comment: Try: connect = 'host=localhost dbname=postfix user=postfix password="blah bluh blih"'

Comment: Unfortunately, neither `connect = 'host=localhost dbname=postfix user=postfix password="blah bluh blih"'` or `connect = "host=localhost dbname=postfix user=postfix password='blah bluh blih'"` are working.

Comment: I advise not using spaces in DB passwords. How about " ... password=\"blah blah\" "?

Comment: Another option maybe connect = 'host=localhost dbname=postfix user=postfix password="blah\ bluh\ blih" although as Rui is right in saying that spaces in passwords is not advised.

Comment: It's not working either. I guess I need to change the password now. Thanks for the help though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dovecot's source code relies on spaces to separate the fields in the connection string.
Therefor, it is advised to use passwords without spaces.
See [this discussion](https://dovecot.org/mailman3/hyperkitty/list/dovecot@dovecot.org/thread/P5U4J2OHRVEG4ZP2BHXCZM3LOUKAAPE6/) on the ML,
which references this [part of dovecot's source code](https://github.com/dovecot/core/blob/main/src/lib-sql/driver-mysql.c#L194)

```
static int driver_mysql_parse_connect_string(struct mysql_db *db,
                         const char *connect_string,
                         const char **error_r)
{
    const char *const *args, *name, *value;
    const char **field;

    db->ssl_cipher = "HIGH";
    db->ssl_verify_server_cert = 1;
    db->connect_timeout = SQL_CONNECT_TIMEOUT_SECS;
    db->read_timeout = MYSQL_DEFAULT_READ_TIMEOUT_SECS;
    db->write_timeout = MYSQL_DEFAULT_WRITE_TIMEOUT_SECS;

    args = t_strsplit_spaces(connect_string, " ");
    for (; *args != NULL; args++) {
        value = strchr(*args, '=');
        if (value == NULL) {
            *error_r = t_strdup_printf("Missing value in connect string: %s",
                           *args);
            return -1;
        }
[...]
```